# Efficient way to sort a column of 2D array

Tags: c#

I need to sort a column of a 2D array. What is the most efficient way to do so? Can I copy the entire column of 2D array to a new 1D array then sort it from there. I need it to be fast.

Comment: Maybe wanna try this? : http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=151

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal [QuickSort](http://begeeben.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/quick-sort-in-c/) and give it another parameter for column index.

```
input[i, columnIndex] = temp;
```